# Sending Password Reset Link In Laravel returning empty array

Tags: laravel, passwords

I am following the docs and trying to send a reset password link.
The only difference is I am using a `Symfony` form for users to enter their email.
When I see what is in my `Request` I see the nested array.
The first array key is the `Symfony` form name of `form` then within that I see an array with a key/value pair of `Email => myemail@gmail.com`

When I get to the status piece and dump `$request->only('Email')` I get an empty array so then I get the error that Laravel cannot find a user with that email. I know `only()` requires an array as well.

Here is what I have tried in my **controller**

```
    $emailAddress = $request->input('form.Email');
    $credentials = ['email' => $emailAddress];
    $status = Password::sendResetLink(
        $request->only($credentials)
    );

    dd(__($status)); // Cannot find user with that email
```

**Array Structure**

```
    array:1 [▼
        "form" => array:1 [▼
            "email" => "myemail@gmail.com"
        ]
    ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not providing your `$credentials` array to the `sendResetLink`. Try this:

```php
$emailAddress = $request->input('form.email');
$credentials = ['email' => $emailAddress];
$status = Password::sendResetLink(
    $credentials
);
```

**Update 1:** 
Also make sure your `User` model (or default `auth` model you use) implements the `CanResetPasswordContract` and uses `CanResetPassword` trait. The default `User` model that is shipped with Laravel has that included already.

**Update 2:**
If you have custom email field name like `user_email`, `org_email` or etc, you need to override the default functionality and add this function inside your `User` model.

```php
public function getEmailForPasswordReset()
{
    return $this->user_email;
}
```

Comment: do you know why I would be getting `Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'email' cannot be null` in the same `sendResetLink` method? It is trying to save to the db but the email field is `null` at the time of saving.

Comment: @PA-GW do you have the `email` field with the same spelling and case inside your `users` table?

Comment: @PA-GW Read the updates I just added, they might help you.